# Spring servlet mapping works only with /*

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-integration

I'm trying to configure a spring `DispatcherServlet` for the path `/statefull/wallet/user/login`.

The path is mapped using a Spring-Integration Inbound HTTP Gateway, as the following:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="gw"
                          supported-methods="POST"
                          request-channel="requestChannel"
                          reply-channel="replyChannel"
                          view-name="/login"
                          path="/statefull/wallet/user/login"
                          reply-timeout="50000">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

My web.xml has the following application context:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        <!-- Spring application context declaration -->
        com.myapp.config.WebAppConfig                 
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myapp.root</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

I tried the 2 following servlet mappings:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
...
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/statefull/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But this is not working. The only configuration that worked for me is:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
...
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I can't keep this second configuration, because I want to have some other servlet mappings, whereas the second configuration will map all the requests to the same servlet.

Any idea, what is the mistake in the first configuration ?

Comment: What is the context root for your web application?

Comment: I've updated my initial description with the context root.

Comment: I am not asking for your configuration. I am asking about what is the context root for your web application. You can get it from eclipse(if you are using) by right clicking the web project, properties, web project setting or while you are deploying.

Comment: Should be /. I'm using maven with the tomcat plugin
`<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>`

Comment: You can use InternalResourceViewResolver to filter the suffix and route.

Comment: Could you provide the `RequestMapping`'s (and a stacktrace, response, and the relevant controller code)?

Comment: Guys thanks for all of your questions ! I understand the problem now, after having enabled traces. What I see is that the `DispatcherServlet` is handling the URL in both cases, but in first case, Spring Integration `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` receives a mapping for `/statefull/wallet/user/login` and in the second case it receives `/wallet/user/login`. So my question would be why is it receiving a different path in both cases ?

Comment: The `path` property is the path inside the `DispatcherServlet` that is processing the request and not the full path. The `DispatcherServlet` or actually the components processing the request, use the path internal to the servlet instead of the full path.